# RxJS: How to emit original values, then reduce upon completion?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I would like to emit all original values from an RxJS stream, and then emit a summary upon completion.

Reduce stops the original values from emitting. Scan emits each total rather than the original values.

Here is my hacky solution:

```
let total = {
  total: 0
};

Rx.Observable.range(1, 3)
  .do(val => {
    total.total += val;
  })
  .concat(Rx.Observable.of(total))
  .subscribe(
    value => {
      console.log('Next:', value)
    }
  );

// Next: 1
// Next: 2
// Next: 3
// Next: { total: 6 }
```

What is a simple way to do this with pure RxJS streams?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use multicast

```
Rx.Observable.range(1, 3)
 .multicast(new Rx.Subject(), (shared)=> {
    return Rx.Observable.merge(shared, shared.reduce((acc, x)=>acc+x,0))
 })
.subscribe(x=>console.log(x))
```

Comment: Interesting, bonus points if you can explain multicast (specifically how the selector function works.) I can't find good documentation on it.

Comment: This video does a great job of explaining, but I believe only Egghead members can watch:
https://egghead.io/lessons/rxjs-multicast-with-a-selector-argument-as-a-sandbox

Comment: it would be shorter to use `.publish((shared)=> Rx.Observable.merge(shared, shared.reduce((acc, x)=>acc+x,0)))`, `publish` is actually using `multicast` [internally](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/file/es6/operator/publish.js.html#lineNumber18).

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you could avoid using `share()` and making two Observable chains and make just a single chain:

```
Observable.range(1, 3)
    .concat(Observable.of(null))
    .scan((obj, curr) => {
        if (curr) {
            obj.acc.push(curr);
        }
        obj.curr = curr;
        return obj;
    }, { acc: [], curr: 0 })
    .map(obj => obj.curr === null
        ? { total: (obj.acc.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0)) }  // count total
        : obj.curr  // just return current item
    )
    .subscribe(console.log);
```

This prints the result you're expecting:

```
1
2
3
{ total: 6 }
```

Even though using `share()` looks very simple be aware that it in fact you subscribe to the source Observable twice. In practise maybe it's not a problem for you depending on what source Observable you'll use.

Try this and see that each number is printed twice:

```
let source = Observable.range(1, 3).do(console.log).share();
```

Comment: You are right that share() runs the subscription twice. This answer is what I was initially thinking, but it complicates the code a lot. The multicast sandbox wins out (and only runs subscription once!)

Answer (score 1):

How about?

```
let source = Observable.range(1, 3).share();

let totalOb = source
    .reduce((total, value) => total + value, 0);

source
    .concat(totalOb)
    .subscribe( value => console.log(`Next: ${value}`) );
```

Output:

```
Next: 1
Next: 2
Next: 3
Next: 6
```

You can use `throw` and `catch` to separate data and summary.

```
let source = Observable.range(1, 3).share();

let totalOb = source
    .reduce((total, value) => total + value, 0)
    .mergeMap(total => Observable.throw(total));

source
    .concat(totalOb)
    .subscribe(
        value => console.log(`Next: ${value}`),
        value => console.log(`Total: ${value}`)
    );
```

Output:

```
Next: 1
Next: 2
Next: 3
Total: 6
```

Comment: The first suggestion looks like a good solution. The second unfortunately I need catch for real error handling.

I'm going to wait a few days for other ideas to come in and will accept an answer.

Comment: I wouldn't use the throw to separate data flows. This would be a better practice:

let source = Observable.range(1, 3).share();

let totalOb = source
    .reduce((total, value) => total + value, 0).map(total => ({total}));

source
    .concat(totalOb)
    .subscribe(value => value.total ? console.log(`Total: ${value.total}`) : console.log(`Next: ${value}`) );

Comment: As @martin points out using share() runs the subscription twice. This is inefficient for HTTP calls or anything that is processor intensive.